# Need to extend bulb life on 13vDC, 100 watt headlights

Tags: resistors

I have a boat, that uses two 13V, 100 watt lights.  The output from my alternator is running at 13.8V-14.5v and it is rated for 90 Amps. These lights run $270/pair and seem to burn out quickly. They are factory rated for only 25 hours at 13v. A technician at a bulb supply store read a chart and told me that running the bulbs at 14v reduces their lifespan by 60%. So, now these expensive bulbs only last for 10 hours.  They are intended for docking the boat only and not continuous use.  The same tech that told me I was burning the lights up so quickly told me if I reduced the voltage in that circuit, I would get a huge increase in the lifespan of those same bulbs. Therefore: I would like to reduce the voltage in the circuit to 12v and still be able to draw the 100 watts to run the lights as needed. IF the solution is impractical, I will look for other lights, but cutting a new hole in the hull of the boat (for new lights) is my last resort.

Comment: Note that if you drop the voltage, using any of the methods mellow, will also reduce the wattage drawn and so, the intensity. There is no way to reduce the voltage to the same lamp without reducing the intensity. It may be at dropping one volt will not reduce the light so much that you care.

Comment: What's so special about those bulbs? Are they made of some special material or with some special housing for marine operations? A quick search on google shows that common halogen bulbs for home applications [like this one (rated 12V /100W)](http://www.lighting.philips.com/main/prof/special-catalog/optical-medical-equipment/halogen-non-reflector/923872517103_EU/product) are much cheaper (under 10EUR). Maybe you can retrofit them, and even if you burn them quickly, they are so much cheaper!

Comment: @Lorenzo : Adding "marine" to a product description automatically increases the price, at least 2x. At least these aren't aircraft grade!

Comment: @BrianDrummond So it is all marketing BS or there is at least some technical justification for that higher price?

Comment: Bit of both, usually. You expect a higher level of testing and paperwork (traceability) to reflect the consequences of faults (e.g. in navigation lights when you're crossing a shipping lane to a tanker terminal). And better materials - such as 316 grade stainless steel bolts. Not that that applies to a lightbulb. But if this is a spotlight I expect its filament has a particular construction to cast the light properly - look at projector bulbs to see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

The lights apparently draw about 8A at 13V if they are rated 100W @13V.

You could drop the voltage slightly by using two or three silicon diodes in series. The total current for two will be about 16A, with a surge of perhaps 150A on turn-on. You will need a fairly hefty diode to withstand that. To take one example, consider two Vishay [VS-40EPF06PBF](http://www.vishay.com/docs/94102/vs-40epf0pbfseries.pdf) diodes in series.

They will typically drop about 1V each at 16A if you keep them reasonably cool.

[image]

It looks like they have an excellent chance of withstanding the surge current too (though perhaps not the fault current when a lamp fails).

[image]

If you're going to drop 2V at 16A, that's 32W to get rid of. If you can find a fairly large piece of aluminum to bolt them to, you'll be fine.

A cheaper and simpler solution is to use a 50W chassis mount resistor. 
A 0.15 ohm resistor such as a [9-1625984-3](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1773035&DocType=DS&DocLang=English) from TE is less than $4. At 16A it will drop 2.5V and dissipate 40W. Again, you'll need a fairly large heatsink or it it will die, but the resistor can be allowed to run hotter than the diodes (100°C is okay).

Personally, I'd probably opt for two resistors (one per lamp) if that was convenient for the wiring, and still use the 50W size. Of course they're going to be double the value each, and the granularity of value choice is a bit better (.25 or 0.3 ohm, so drop will be 2V or 2.4V each).

[image]

Note that if your lamps are halogen type running them at below rated voltage may result in darkening of the bulb because the halogen cycle won't operate properly- but in this case you're mostly trying to get them to rated voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Cutting a new hole might not be needed, if you work from bare PCB mounted LEDs with a bunch of DIY.
But that'll include a lot of steps, both electrically, and probably optically - since your lamps are expensive, there must be a reason - that you might not want to think about now.

You tagged this "Resistors", so: Yes, you can use resistors.

If it's 100W per lamp rated at 13V, that will come down to a smidge below 7.7A, using: I = P / V.

Let's assume the current drops linearly (it doesn't, but we'll assume, for ease, since it's only a volt) when you decrease the voltage, you'll be working with 12/13th the current, so:
(12 * 7.7) / 13 = 7.1A.

Now you have a maximum working system voltage of 14.5V, assuming your info is right. And you say you want to run the lamp at a maximum of 12V, so we need to take those two voltages.

This means the resistor will have to handle 14.5V - 12V = 2.5V

First off: This means that the resistor will need to be 2.5V * 7.5A (be pessimistic with the current, to be sure) = 19W, so make that at least 25W to avoid smoke and fire. A 25W resistor for each lamp may not be cheap either, but, up to you, you know the price of a lamp and how willing you are to try any of the other solutions below.

The value of the resistor is given by R = V / I.
So, that would be: R = 2.5V / 7.1A = 0.35Ohm.
Putting 3 resistors of 1.1Ohm at 8W in parallel might be a start (0.367 Ohm).

If you mean it's 100W in total for all lights, you can use this result for all lamps in parallel, or do the maths yourself per lamp and see which of the two solutions is the most affordable.

Make sure you mount the resistors as indicated by their datasheets for their power limit to mean something and then still count on them getting warm to hot.

### Not Resistors

You can also not use resistors.
First: You can use several high power Diodes in series. Each will "drop" the voltage by about 0.8V to 1.2V (would depend on the type, refer to datasheets). Make sure they can handle well above the maximum current (>15A for the 100W path), to allow for cold starts and spikes.

They will still consume all the unused energy, but the voltage they "eat" is much less dependant on the exact current, so in all use cases the lamps will see something closer to 12V than with the resistor might happen.

Say their datasheet says they are 0.8V at 8A, then you just put 3 in series and make sure you mount them such that they can get rid of their heat:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1vzHR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each will generate P = V * I = 0.8V * 7.5V = 6W in heat. The datasheet will sometimes say a diode can handle that, but often they supply guidelines about how to mount them (screw them onto or into a piece of metal with sufficient surface, for example). If you don't do what they suggest the diodes will still melt.

### Possibly Even Better (but some electronics knowledge may be required)

EDIT: Whether this is really better, depends a bit on the dynamics. In the case of a single 100W lamp, it may cost more than the resistors and power savings are very minimal with the most likely modules.

Find yourself an affordable Low-Drop Buck converter, or even better a high-power SEPIC converter (In China referred to as Buck-Boost Module, in case you wonder).

Usually the cheaper ones will have a little 10 turn screw-potentiometer to set the output voltage, so you can always tweak that.

For a buck converter the output needs to be a little lower than the input, so starting an engine, or low battery power, etc, might make it hiccup if it is set to 12V out and the input falls below 12.5V. Specific number will depend on the exact unit and technology used. Some bucks can go down to their output voltage on their input, but never lower.

A SEPIC (buck-boost) unit will try to make the set voltage at al times, regardless of the input, so long as that input is between its limits.

So, for example if the minimum is 6V and the maximum is 40V, then the input can be anywhere between those and it'll still make the set voltage.
Do mind, that with a 100W load they can be somewhat expensive and that they will draw at least I-in = 1.1*100 / Vin

So if your Vin is only 9V, they will need to be able to draw 110W/9V = 12.3A

If you are going full-electronic, you will need to take care of a little bit of filtering before the module, because cheap ones never do and your generator and electrical system can make a lot of noise:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9xfDZ.png)</sup>

Make the cap at least 40V, the inductor at least 10A saturation, 15A if possible and make sure the TVS (Transient Voltage Supressor) Diode has a break down voltage below the maximum input voltage of your module. Usually a mid-sized type in the $1 to $4 range will handle sufficient energy to take out the real pesky spikes.

The inductor can be larger in value, but I expect past 10uH it'll start really costing. The capacitor value should be good enough for most buck converters to filter out the remaining wobbles, but you can very easily up that to 100uF or even more, but if you make it more than 100uF, best to make it multiple caps of 100uF each.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that reducing the voltage to a lamp with an incandescent type filament can extend the lifespan of the lamp. But at the same time be prepared to see a reduction in the amount of light output.

Probably the easiest way for you to reduce the voltage to the lamps in your situation would be to place heavy duty power diodes in series with each of the lamps. A 13V lamp rated at 100W will be consuming just under 8A per bulb. At first turn-on the lamps will consume even more current until the filament heats up. You would want to use power diodes that were rated for a continuous current of 10A or more. Each diode in series will reduce the voltage somewhere from 0.7V to 1.2V or so. So to reduce by 2V you can place two diodes in series with each lamp. Choose three diodes in series to reduce the voltage even more.

If you used a diode type like a Fairchild FFH75H60S (pictured below) it would be relatively easy for you to mount and connect to your existing wiring.

[image]

This particular diode is rated at 75A with a surge rating ten times that. This part number will forward voltage drop at the 0.8V to 0.9V per diode at your nomimal 8A of current.

Keep in mind that running current of 8A at 0.9V through these diodes will be dissipating some 7.2W per diode so you will want to make sure that you mount these on a good metal heat sinking surface capable of spreading the heat out.

The above mentioned diodes are about $3 each if you buy a hand full of them. [Online retailers](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Fairchild-Semiconductor/FFH75H60S/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtbRapU8LlZD6KDHQne%252bIW05ns8V1cV%252bYI%3D) would be happy to sell them to you.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and cheap method to get longer life out of those outrageously-priced bulbs is to wire 2 in series. Side effect is a rather large drop in illumination.

A better long-term solution is different bulbs. Go to a car accessories shop and look at off-road or fog lamps. Maybe even HID - I've seen HID kits for motorbikes that are around $100 a pair, bright as the sun, and designed for continuous use. It seems like it won't take long to pay off the refit.

$135 for a bulb that only lasts 25 hours is on the high side of extortionary. It's also more than the minimum hourly wage in some states.

Comment: In my experience, everything for a boat costs ~3x, for an aircraft ~10x and for space... astronomical.

Comment: I used to work at an airport. Hydraulic pump for boat, same pump for airplane. Same maker, same size, same fittings, same color. Aviation part number was 10x the price of the marine model.